# How to do password validation in oracle forms 6i to restrict to enter atleast 1 Capital Letter 1 Number 1 Special Character

Tags: forms, oracle, validation, password-encryption, oracleforms

How to Restrict Password Field in oracle Forms 6i?
In Password Field user should enter At Least one of the following:

- one Capital Letter
- one Number
- one Special Character

Should I write Trigger code for that or is there any possibility to change in property palette?

Comment: do u got my doubt now ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an Oracle database account password?

If yes, set this validation using PROFILE. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm for detail. You can write own validation function and set it by profile.

If no, use WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger on your password item. In property palette you can't set it.